# Highcharts. How to start areaspline chart from start y axis?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, next.js

I am new to highcharts so i might be missing something here.
Recently i was working on area chart and i was able to draw the chart and everything is perfect, But i have a requirement where i have area chart should start from x as 0. Is there any way to do this ? I have attached a screenshot and fiddle link.
Here is fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/shantanugade/9vwxm412/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'area'
},

title: {
    text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
},
xAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
        }
    },
    accessibility: {
        rangeDescription: 'Range: 1940 to 2017.'
    }
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
    },
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
        }
    }
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name} had stockpiled <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
},
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        pointStart: 1940,
        marker: {
            enabled: false,
            symbol: 'circle',
            radius: 2,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'USA',
    data: [
        null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235,
        369, 640, 1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468,
        20434, 24126, 27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342,
        26662, 26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
        24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586, 22380,
        21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950, 10871, 10824,
        10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104, 9914, 9620, 9326,
        5113, 5113, 4954, 4804, 4761, 4717, 4368, 4018
    ]
}, {
    name: 'USSR/Russia',
    data: [ 1605, 2471, 3322, 4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538,
        5000, 2500, 500, 1200, 1500, 2000, 4260, 6600, 8690, 10600,
        1605, 2471, 3322, 4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538,
        11643, 13092, 14478, 15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935,
        30062, 32049, 33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000,
        37000, 35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
        21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000, 15537, 14162, 12787,
        12600, 11400, 5500, 4512, 4502, 4502, 4500, 4500
    ]
}] })
```

[image: As you can see in the image there is small gap]

As You can see in the image there is small gap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce `xAxis.minPadding` property:

```
    xAxis: {
        minPadding: 0,
        ...
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k2mzg0yq/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minPadding